# Cannot declare class because the name is already in use

Tags: php, symfony

I am learning symfony framework and during the seperation of concern part https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/separation_of_concerns.html the output shows

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class Calendar\Controller\LeapYearController, because the name is already in use in /home/developer/shadowmap/abhed-workspace/training/php-training/my-framework/src/Calender/Controller/LeapYearController.php on line 9

I tried to navigate the error and the problem is in controllerResolver (vendor/symfony/httpKernel/controller/ControllerResolver.php)

```
 protected function instantiateController(string $class)
{
    return new $class();
}
```

that means this class has initialized earlier.

Do anyone faced this issue or just me ? Need to tag more images (the link provided has all the code) ?

Comment: The first thing to check is if you accidentally defined the class twice. Search your codebase for `class LeapYearController` and see what it returns.

Comment: no .. only one in the app.php routing '_controller'

Comment: @El_Vanja is there any problem with symfony?

Comment: Assuming there is not a duplicate class then this is typically a caching problem.  Not sure exactly where you are in creating the framework but if you do have something like var/cache then delete it.  Symfony itself is fine.  It's quite possible to make mistakes when following a tutorial.  And for future info, [don't use images in questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: @Cerad thanks i ve changed the question and i checked there is no var/cache in my code base .. thats what u said?

Comment: @AbhedIndulkar That is indeed what I suggested doing.  What PHP version are you using?  You could try just rebooting your workstation since sometime PHP itself can cache stuff.  Very unlikely that it will help.  You could checkin what you have to a github repo and post a link.  But from what you described, it will probably run on another machine just fine.  And if you search for "php because the name is already in use" you will see lots and lots of questions on this most of which mysteriously resolve themselves.

Comment: check that you are not using a method the same name of the class.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Create an answer instead.